# Questions on Lattices & Posets/Stanley EC1, Ch 3

Tags: combinatorics, order-theory, lattice-orders

I'm trying to solve a couple of problems from Stanley's Enumerative Combinatorics Vol 1, 2nd Edition and feel quite clueless about how to approach them:

Q34. Find all non-isomorphic posets P such that
$F (J (P ), x) = (1 + x)(1 + x^2 )(1 + x + x^2 )$

It is clear after expanding the RHS that the coefficients are 123321 for $x^0, x^1, \ldots , x^5$ and the set has 5 elements, but I'm not sure if there is a intuitive or direct way of finding ALL the non isomorphic posets. Any help would be appreciated!

Q46a. Let $f(n)$ be the number of sublattices of rank n of the Boolean algebra $B_n$. Show that $f(n)$ is also the number of partial orders $P$ on $[n]$.

I'm completely stuck on how to go about this proof. As fas I could tell, there is no explicit formula for the number of partial orders on [n]. How could one determine $f(n)$?

PLEASE let me know your suggestions. Thank you so much for all your help!

Comment: What are F and J?   How does the x formula relate to an order?   Is x a real number and how do real numbers relate to the problem?

Comment: The set of all order ideals of P, ordered by inclusion, forms a poset denoted by J(P). F(P,x) is the rank generating function of poset P. So F(P,x) = $sum$ ($p_i x^i$)